# Dudas con parse_dates en pd.read_csv() / pd.read_excel()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

En el siguiente enlace, [carpeta Ficheros_R4](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17TOOa64J_KFRL39NMMIT0qWwHcgAfKII?usp=sharing)

disponemos del  archivo TrueValue.csv, con cotizaciones histórics de este valor.

Intento importarlas a un DataFrame haciendo:

```
os.chdir("/path/")
df = pd.read_csv("TrueValue.csv",  decimal  =",", sep='\t')   
df.info()
```

Características del df creado:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1628 entries, 0 to 1627
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Date    1627 non-null   object 
 1   Close   1626 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 25.6+ KB
```

Como la fecha está importada con el tipo 'object', intento convertirla a datetime utilizando 'parse_date'

```
df = pd.read_csv("TrueValue.csv",  decimal  =",", sep='\t', parse_dates=['Date'])     
df.info()
```

Me devuelve:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1628 entries, 0 to 1627
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Date    1627 non-null   object 
 1   Close   1626 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 25.6+ KB
```

Como no lo ha hecho, lo intento haciendo:

```
df = pd.read_csv("TrueValue.csv",  decimal  =",", parse_dates = True, sep='\t')  
df.info()
```

Vuelvo a intentarlo sin éxito haciendo:

```
df = pd.read_csv("TrueValue.csv",  decimal  =",", parse_dates = True, index_col = 0, sep='\t')
```

Importa la columna 'Date' como índice, pero no modifica su tipo de datos:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1628 entries, 20/12/2013 to  
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Close   1626 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 25.4+ KB

:
```

Se, que puedo conseguirlo haciendo:

```
df = pd.read_csv("TrueValue.csv",  decimal  =",", parse_dates = True, na_values = ["nan"], sep='\t') 
df['Date'] = truevalue['Date'].astype('datetime64')
df.info()
```

Que me devuelve:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1628 entries, 0 to 1627
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Date    1626 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   Close   1626 non-null   float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 25.6 KB
```

Pero no es este el objeto de mi pregunta, si no, ¿por qué no me funciona 'df.parse_date()?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Buen día, hice una prueba y cree el dataframe con los datos que pusiste en la foto y tal como tu lo declaras `df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv',  decimal  =",", sep='\t', parse_dates=['Date'])` a mi me funciona correctamente:  `0   Date    2 non-null      datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: No logro reproducir tu mismo escenario, en mi caso `read_csv()` convierte la columna a fecha, ¿pdrías compartir una muestra del CSV en formato de texto?

Comment: ¿Puedo indicarte  una dirección en github, en la que está el fichero y podrias descargarlo?

Comment: Date Close
07/01/2014 10
08/01/2014 10,005
09/01/2014 9,915
10/01/2014 10,024
13/01/2014 9,92
14/01/2014 10,03
15/01/2014 10,025
16/01/2014 10,068
17/01/2014 9,995
20/01/2014 9,98
21/01/2014 10,107
22/01/2014 10,227

Comment: @efueyo, si puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar el URL o los datos sería mejor, tal como está descrita tu pregunta a mi me funciona de forma correcta